# What does "movl $0x4050, (%eax)" do?

Tags: assembly, x86

Let's say that register %eax contains address 0x100 and at address 0x100 there is a value 0x3999.

From what I understand "%eax" returns the address, for example movl $0x4050, %eax, moves the value 0x4050 at address 0x100.

But "(%eax)" returns the value at the address, meaning 0x3999. So what does movl $0x4050, (%eax) do? Is it going to treat the constant 0x3999 as an address?

Comment: `movl $0x4050, %eax` puts the value `0x4050` into the register `eax`.  It does not in any way use the value that was already in `eax`.  `movl $0x4050, (%eax)` stores the value `0x4050` to memory at  address `0x100`.  It does not in any way use the value that was previously at that address.  X86 assembly is difficult because `mov` is overloaded to mean load from memory, store to memory, and move to register.  Other assembly languages might have different opcodes for each type of move.

Answer (score 3):

If you're familiar with C, think of it like this:

```
movl $0x100, %eax     // int* eax = (int*)0x100;
movl $0x4050, (%eax)  // *eax = 0x4050;
```

`movl $0x4050, %eax` just overwrites `%eax` with the value `0x4050`.  Nothing is interpreted as an address in this case.

Comment: Funny story, I'm learning this to properly understand pointers, so now I need to understand pointers to understand this... I'm doomed. Any possible non-pointer explanation?

Comment: Oh dear... that's an unconventional order :)  What languages are you most familiar with, if any?

Comment: I'm learning C atm and that's the only language you could say I'm "familiar"(that's streching it though) with.

Answer (score 1):

Do not generally think about registers containing addresses, think of registers containing values. Those values might be treated as addresses if they are used in certain contexts.

`%eax` just is an *expression* that refers to the register called eax. Even if I started to write this paragraph in a different way, `%eax` is not the same as `0x100`, even if the register `%eax` contains the value 0x100. It depends on the context in which you name a register whether the value of that register is relevant at all.

Now, you are putting parenthesis around an expression, you are indicating that you are talking about a *memory location*, whose address is the *value* of the expression. In a context where just the value of an expression is used, an expression naming a register may be replaced by a constant expression having the same value as the register. In this case `(%eax)` is equivalent to `($0x100)` (if you may write it that way), that is, the memory location at the address 0x100. The AT&T syntax used by the GNU assembler by default lets you write just `0x100` instead of `($0x100)` to refer to the memory location at address 0x100. If an instruction is going to access memory, you need to tell that instruction, what location it should access. Note that I did not talk about the way that memory is accessed, as this depends on the specific instruction.

Now, you were talking about `movl $0x4050, (%eax)`. So the memory location is mentioned in the second operand of the move instruction. In AT&T syntax, this is the target operand of the move instruction. The target of the move instruction is in this case: "The *memory location* at the address indicated by the *value* stored in `%eax`",  so if `%eax` is 0x100, the target of the move is "The *memory location* at the address 0x100". Note that up to now we did not talk about the *contents* of that memory location, just about the location itself. The `mov` instruction (you have to learn these specifics for any instruction) does not care about the value stored in the location indicated by the target operand, but it will store a copy of the *value* of the source operand at the *location* indicated by the second operand, overwriting the previous value. So the 0x3999 stored at address 0x100 does not matter at all, but after execution, it has been replaced by 0x4050.

Comment: Thank you, from what I understand it's all about how mov works, it gets itself a memory location. I imagined that low level programming languages would have very clear instrunctions, too bad.

Comment: No, mov does not get itself a memory location. mov uses the memory location you specify, by putting its address into %eax before invoking the mov instruction. It's just that mov only *writes* to that location, but does not *read* it.